# Where can I find documentation for the Erlang shell?

Tags: erlang

The [Erlang documentation](http://www.erlang.org/doc/) contains the documentation of modules.

Where can I find the documentation of the Erlang shell? (Which is not a module, I suppose.)

Comment: The answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063497/hidden-features-of-erlang) is really useful for a list of some shell commands I've never seen documented anywhere else...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This page in the documentation](http://www.erlang.org/doc/getting_started/seq_prog.html#2.1) seems to be a starting point. Especially the link in it. Check also the [first link](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/shell.html) in it, with the shell's manpage.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [Getting Started with Erlang](http://www.erlang.org/download/getting_started-5.4.pdf), chapter 1.2.1. It's about the shell and brings you up to speed on usage, etc..

Answer (score 1):

I think Erlang shell is also a module.
Take a look at this: [Erlang shell](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/shell.html)

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://carpanta.dc.fi.udc.es/docs/erlang/dbg.html) might also be helpful, as well as [this](http://www.ejabberd.im/interconnect-erl-nodes).