# Elixir into Erlang transformation

Tags: elixir

I want to see what happens when elixir gets transformed into beam files. Is there any way to print in console or in a file how it is translated? I want to know what would this module look like in erlang.

I was thinking if there is a debug mode of elixir, which would output any of the above.

More specifically I have this example:

```
defmodule Test do
    def t1(a), do: a
    def t1(a, b \\ 2), do: a + b
end
```

The above code raises a warning, which is understanable considering what I've done. Basically I want to understand a bit more what's happening.

Comment: If you're trying to get `a` only, you'll have to pass a `0` as the second parameter.  If you don't pass a second parameter, you'll get `a + 2`

Comment: If i understood you correct, then you are wrong. If you call `Test.t1(0)` the output is `0`, but if you call `Test.t1(0, 4)` then the outcome is `4`. Basically everytime you call the function with one argument you end up invoking the first one. Btw, I'm on elixir 1.3.4

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, you need to compile the Elixir module to a .beam file:

```
$ cat test.ex
defmodule Test do
    def t1(a), do: a
    def t1(a, b \\ 2), do: a + b
end
$ elixirc test.ex
warning: this clause cannot match because a previous clause at line 2 always matches
  test.ex:3
```

This will generate `Elixir.Test.beam`. Then, you can decompile this .beam to Erlang source using the following escript (I copied this from some answer here on Stackoverflow a while ago. Unfortunately I can't seem to locate the exact source but this code is in many answers here including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1069185/320615).):

```
$ cat decompile.erl
#!/usr/bin/env escript

main([BeamFile]) ->
  {ok,{_,[{abstract_code,{_,AC}}]}} = beam_lib:chunks(BeamFile,[abstract_code]),
  io:fwrite("~s~n", [erl_prettypr:format(erl_syntax:form_list(AC))]).
```

Then run it:

```
$ escript decompile.erl Elixir.Test.beam
-compile(no_auto_import).

-file("test.ex", 1).

-module('Elixir.Test').

-export(['__info__'/1, t1/1, t1/2]).

-spec '__info__'(attributes | compile | exports |
         functions | macros | md5 | module |
         native_addresses) -> atom() |
                      [{atom(), any()} |
                       {atom(), byte(), integer()}].

'__info__'(functions) -> [{t1, 1}, {t1, 2}];
'__info__'(macros) -> [];
'__info__'(info) ->
    erlang:get_module_info('Elixir.Test', info).

t1(a@1) -> a@1;
t1(x0@1) -> t1(x0@1, 2).

t1(a@1, b@1) -> a@1 + b@1.
```

Comment: The whole stuff might be easily done inside `IEx`, see my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @mudasobwa yep, but I mostly use this with Mix projects and it's much easier to do it from the command line for that, e.g. (with an alias) `decompile-beam _build/dev/lib/my_app/ebin/Elixir.MyApp.User.beam`.

Comment: @Dogbert Fair enough. I was mostly talking about getting `beam` bytes directly in `IEx`.

Comment: I have to say that this script is awesome!

Answer (score 5):

This probably should be more of a comment to @Dogbert’s answer above, but I would post it as a separate answer for the sake of formatting.

One does not need to create `.ex` files and invoke the compiler on them to produce beams:

```
{:module, _, bytecode, _} =
  defmodule Elixir.Test do
    def t1(a), do: a
    def t1(a, b \\ 2), do: a + b
  end
# File.write!("Elixir.Test.beam", bytecode)
```

now you might have had a beam file written (we have it stored in the `bytecode` variable by the way.)

*NB:* [`beam_lib:chunks/2`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/beam_lib.html) works if and only the beam contains unencrypted debug information (elixir beams by default do.)

Also, you don’t need to *write* decompiled erlang code, you might simply pass a binary there, directly in `Elixir`:

```
:beam_lib.chunks(bytecode, [:abstract_code])
```

To extract the code itself:

```
{:ok,{_,[abstract_code: {_, code}]}} = 
   bytecode |> :beam_lib.chunks([:abstract_code])
```

Now `code` contains the code, it should be enough to examine it, but you still are free to use erlang build-ins:

```
code |> :erl_syntax.form_list
```

or:

```
code |> :erl_syntax.form_list |> :erl_prettypr.format
```

The latter will give you the <s>binary</s> charlist, containing erlang code, exactly as in @Dogbert’s answer. Use `IO.puts` to output it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!